# Floating a slider out of its parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering whether it's possible to float out a DIV out of it's parent by any chance? I have this PHP CMS which uses templates. layout.cpl is the general template for all pages. In it, I have this code to display the main body of the page...

```
<div class="boxmain">Content here</div>
```

I have added a jQuery slider, which is only supposed to appear on certain pages, therefore it's inside the boxmain div, because it's the parent. The thing with the slider is, it's supposed to be a horizontal full-page width banner, hence I need it to float out. If I don't, it uses the 100% width of the "boxmain" div instead.

I hope I made this one clear, it might be a bit confusing, but my basic aim is to get a child div out of it's parent div, to be able to satisfy the full-page width of the sliding banner.

This is the code for the slider in another template that basically displays one of the subpages:

```
<div class="slicebox-wrapper">
    <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider" style="margin-top: -12px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
        <li><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/scripts/slicebox/img/ab1.jpg" alt="image1"/></li>
        <li><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/scripts/slicebox/img/ab2.jpg" alt="image2"/></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: I am a little lost as to what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: I'll include a picture, tells a thousand words. My basic aim is to get a child div out of it's parent div. `slicebox-wrapper` from `boxmain`, but keeping it inside `boxmain`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your question, so I might be wrong, but it sounds to me like you might be interested in removing the element from its current div and placing it somewhere else in the body.  You could use remove() and append(), prepend(), after(), etc to change where that div is located in the document.

You'd have to trigger the function to perform the move when the slider is loaded.  If the page is static, you can just do it on $(document).ready. But if you're using AJAX to load that div, embed a script tag in the HTML that gets passed in the Response that calls the function.

Page:

```
<body>
    <div class="boxmain">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="slicebox-wrapper">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.slicebox-wrapper').remove().appendTo('.boxmain');
});
```

will reorganize the page like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="boxmain">
        <div class="parent"></div>
        <div class="slicebox-wrapper">...</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting the slider to be 100% of the screen size when it is contained in something smaller than 100%.  If that is the case, I would kind of urge against that.  It would be more practical to wrap your slider and content div(s) within a 100% width wrapper:

```
    <div class='mainWrapper'>
        //100% Width Wrapper
        <div class="slicebox-wrapper">
           <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider" style="margin-top: -12px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
              <li><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/scripts/slicebox/img/ab1.jpg" alt="image1"/></li>
              <li><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/scripts/slicebox/img/ab2.jpg" alt="image2"/></li>
              </ul> 
        </div>
        //Fixed Width Wrapper
        <div class='content'>

        </div>
  </div>
```